# how to read guitar tabs finger style

Tags: acoustic-guitar, fingerstyle-guitar

I have recently started learning guitar and would like to learn to read the tabs mentioned in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JUh9xBv3Y0), I have tried searching on the internet but couldn't find a helpful resource.

Any help would be really appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Still added to save going offsite.

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking for a complete explanation on how to read tabs?

Comment: yes that is what I'm asking. if you can point me out to a good resource that would be even better.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is too broad for this site, and references to external resources are off topic. If the question can be broken down into a more specific problem related to tab-reading, it would be a better fit.

Comment: I recommend simply googling "how to read guitar tab." It's really pretty simple; the lines represent guitar strings and the numbers show which fret to press.

Comment: @rohithsantosh the trouble with this question is not well focused. The answer on "how to read tabs" can be as concise as the one given by Divizna, but if you try to go deeper into the details, you could write a book about it.

Answer (score 2):

Each line is a string, the numbers represent a fret (0 means play open string), the stems below clue you to the length (which is unusual, more often you just do with position in the bar).

Comment: I wouldn't say stems are unusual, you can find them in old tabulatures, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tablature#/media/File:Vihuela-Tab_Fuenllana_1554.jpg I would say they were omitted during the period when people were writing tabulatures using just ASCII characters